# What's the difference between the 'remote-control' and 'remote-access' tags? Should they be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are 19 questions tagged [remote-control](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-control).

There are 7 questions tagged [remote-access](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-access). (Of these, 5 are also tagged [remote-control](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-control); 2 are not.)

What's the difference between the two tags? Should they be merged?

Comment: I imagine "remote control" is referring to seeing the "desktop" as if you were sitting in front of it. "Remote access" doesn't necessarily imply seeing the UI while accessing the device.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe de-synonym [remote-desktop](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop) for Android-controlling-non-Android and use [remote-access](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-access) for controlling-Android-from-anything.

Also, perhaps [remote-control](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-control) could be repurposed for questions regarding the IR emitters some devices (Samsung GS4 and Galaxy Mega, HTC One, LG Optimus G Pro, etc.) are starting to include.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree to merging them.

[remote-control](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-control) is described as as:

> Remotely control your Android device **from any other device/computer**,
>   or vice versa.

[remote-access](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-access) is described as:

> Methods to remotely access a device **from another device**, where at
>   least one of the two should be running Android.

Interestingly, [remote-desktop](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop) is a synonym of [remote-access](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-access), which makes it even more confusing if Al Everett describes [remote-control](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-control) as seeing the "desktop".

**UPDATE #1:** However, we could probably make a distinction between:

- Accessing an Android device from another device (may or may not be an Android device)
- Accessing a non-Android device from an Android device

However, the second point may be useless, given that it may be via Bluetooth, Wi-Fi, etc

Comment: Yeah, except accessing the file system of your device from, say, your PC over wifi is in no wise "remote control". It _is_ remote access, though. I suggest there is a distinction; we just need to get the wikis to illustrate that (and tag questions appropriately).